# Non-greedy in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I try to understand the non-greedy regex in python, but I don't understand why the following examples have this results:

```
print(re.search('a??b','aaab').group())
ab
print(re.search('a*?b','aaab').group())
aaab
```

I thought it would be 'b' for the first and 'ab' for the second.
Can anyone explain that?

Comment: The reason is that the regex engine parses the string from left to right and returns the first possible match at the leftmost position. The fact you use a non-greedy quantifier doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the matches you are asking match *afterwards*. If you try to follow how the matching for `a??b` happens from left to right you'll see something like this:

- Try 0 `a` plus `b` vs `aaab`: no match  (`b != a`)
- Try 1 `a` plus `b` vs `aaab` : no match (`ab != aa`)
- Try 0 `a` plus `b` vs `aab`: no match   (`b != a`) (match position moved to the right by one)
- Try 1 `a` plus `b` vs `aab` : no match  (`ab != aa`)
- Try 0 `a` plus `b` vs `ab`: no match   (`b != a`) (match position moved to the right by one)
- Try 1 `a` plus `b` vs `ab` : **match** (`ab == ab`)

Similarly for `*?`.

The fact is that the `search` function returns the *leftmost* match. Using `??` and `*?` changes only the behaviour to prefer the *shortest leftmost* match but it will *not* return a shorter match that starts at the right of an already found match.

Also note that the `re` module doesn't return overlapping matches, so even using `findall` or `finditer` you will not be able to find the two matches you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of that `??` is [*lazy*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) while `?` is greedy.and a lazy quantifier will match zero or one (its left token), zero if that still allows the overall pattern to match.for example all the following will returns an empty string :

```
>>> print(re.search('a??','a').group())

>>> print(re.search('a??','aa').group())

>>> print(re.search('a??','aaaa').group())
```

And the regex `a??b` will match `ab` or `b` :

```
>>> print(re.search('a??b','aaab').group())
ab
>>> print(re.search('a??b','aacb').group())
b
```

And if it doesn't allows the overall pattern to match and there was not any `b` it will return None :

```
>>> print(re.search('a??b','aac').group())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

And about the second part you have a none-greedy regex and the result is very obvious.It will match any number of `a` and then `b`:

```
print(re.search('a*?b','aaab').group())
aaab
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for the Pattern - `/a??b/`

`a??` matches the character `a` literally (case sensitive), Then the quantifier
`??` means Between zero and one time, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy], then character `b` should match, literally (case sensitive)

So It will match last `'ab'` characters in the given string `'aaab'`

And For Pattern - `/a*?b/`

`a*?` matches the character `'a'` literally (case sensitive)
Here the Quantifier `*?` means between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy] then character `b` should match, literally (case sensitive).

So It will match `'aaab'` as a whole in `'aaab'`